# How can I edit the same bibliography in Jabref on multiple machines?

Tags: jabref, workflow

Do I have to copy and share both the .bib and .bak file?

Is this even possible?

Comment: You need to carry/share only the `.bib` file. Be good in synchronization though .:)

Comment: If you want to edit your bibliography *simultaneously* on multiple machines you should use a MySQL-server: http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/SQLExport.php

Comment: The `bak`ckup file is just a copy of the bib-file. I'm not sure this is really on-topic here, except for the question of what the `.bak` file is. You could use Dropbox, or a version control system such as git connected to e.g. Bitbucket.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks. Feel free to flag it if you think it is unrelated.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks, good to know. Don't know what exactly you mean by *good in in synchronization* though, maybe something was lost in the translation? :)

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure, so I'll leave it for others to decide.

Comment: @henry You edit in some PC and then the other PC will have old version. If this is done many times, different PCs will have different versions unless you synchronise. You should never forget to synchronise or use some version control.

Comment: @HarishKumar Oh, right! I assumed it was an obviously implied part of the inquiry, as it is a rather inherent characteristic to the whole issue.

Comment: @HarishKumar I'd like to close this question. Imho you answered it. Please do provide some sort of (short/simple) summary of your comments so I can mark it.

Comment: Henry, I have converted my comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is enough to carry only the `.bib` file. `.bak` files are the backup files created by JabRef and they are the copies of `.bib` files useful in case you damage the original file.

Since you are modifying the bib file on different computers, it would be better to use some version control like Git or Dropbox etc so that synchronisation becomes easy, otherwise you may end up with a mess.

Answer (score 1):

JabRef supports synchronizing the local `.bib` file with an SQL backend server: http://help.jabref.org/en/SQLDatabase